# read filesize while uploading it through ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload, filesize

i'm trying to read the filesize of a file while uploading it this way

1 . start an $.ajax(); request to start a server to server downloading of file (i'm using php `fopen` + `stream_copy_to_stream` );

2 . start a second $a.ajax(); request each tot time and try to read the current filesize till the end of download process;

unfortunely this don't work as expected.

both the requests are made correctly but the filesize is read only after the file is fully transfered. so i get all the alert message at the end of the process instead of meanwhile

i guess i'm doing something that can't be done? or i'm just missing something?

pseudo code:

```
var uploadStart = 0;
function startUploadProgressBar(file) {
    var file = file;
    uploadStart = setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            data: 'uploadProgress=1&file=' + file,
            success: function(json) {
                alert(json.filesize)
            }
        });

    },
    1000);
}
$('#submit').click(function() {
    var file = somevar;
    startUploadProgressBar(file);
    $.ajax({
        success: function(json) {
            clearInterval(uploadStart);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for uploading files via ajax, you can consider using the jQuery forms plugin. It supports progress bars, as far as I know.

If you want to stick to your method, read through the comments of the [function's manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-copy-to-stream.php) in the PHP manual. There are alternatives that can be modified outputting states of the transfer.

Comment: i'm uploading not from client to server but server to server

Answer (score 0):

Why not just have the PHP page return the size of the file itself using [filesize()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php)? That way you don't need to poll repeatedly.

Comment: i need to get the filesize() progressively not just at the end! do you understand?

Comment: You're wanting to generate a progress bar for your upload. Use `filesize()` on the file before the start of the transfer, to get the total file size without any file-access problems. Then keep track of how much of the file you've transferred. The ratio is your progress bar update.

If that isn't what you're doing, you need to update the question to clarify things a bit more.